# How to rename specific recorded observation values in a single variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

Trying to rename recorded observation values for a specific variable: "cyl" in mtcars. The specific question/variable asks respondents to record their answer as one of three numeric values (4,6,or 8).  I want to correlate these numeric observation values with the names "Four Cylinder", "Six Cylinder", and "Eight Cylinder".

*Note that this question has been altered to use an easier, more accessible dataset and shorter/easier variables - the intention being to streamline the basic syntax*

```
mtcars = mtcars %>% 
data.frame(cyl =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L)) |>
  mutate(
    cyl = factor(
      cyl,
      levels = c(4,6,8),
      labels = c(
        "Four Cylinder",
        "Six Cylinder",
        "Eight Cylinder"
      )
    )
  ) 
ggplot() +
geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

Comment: Please share a little bit of sample data so that we have something to demonstrate solutions on.

Comment: (Also, you're missing a `"` in your `6 = ` line.)

Comment: Yes, thank you for identifying that. I reran the code with that fix and still nothing. This is what the error message/code says:

Error: unexpected '=' in:
"HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df |>
mutate(B36 = recode(B36, 1 ="

I'm thinking that the mutate function is wrong for my purposes here?

Comment: How can I share sample data on this platform?

Comment: @GregorThomas I added the `"` to avoid derailing the OP's intent.

Comment: The typical ways to share data in the R tag are: (a) use `dput()` which creates copy/pasteable R code to reproduce an R object to share a little sample data. For example `dput(HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df[1:6, ])` would give code to create the first 6 rows of your data. (b) share some code to simulate sample data with the same structure as your real data. (c) Use a built-in dataset, such as mtcars, iris, diamonds, etc.

Comment: No, mutate is fine here. But after the mutate you probably want `|>` not `,`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in sharing these insights.  Is this what you had in mind with the dput()?  I just plugged in the code you gave me, but then the output was massive because there a few hundred variables.  So I scaled back and only have the one variable we are looking into.  And then I just copy and pasted the results. 
 Is this what you had in mind with dput()?`dput(HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df[1:6, c("B36") ]) `
c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L)

Comment: Also, why do the results all have an "L" attached to the left of the recorded observation value?  Those "L's" are not included in the original dataset answers - what do they mean in the context of dput()?

Comment: an `L` after a number means that is specifically an `integer`, not just a `numeric` - you can see `class(1)` vs `class(1L)`.  And yes, that `dput` output is just fine.

Comment: Ok cool.  I can also use the mtcars data as an example because they have a super similar situation in that data set for cyclinder size (4,6, or 8).  Whatever is easiest.  Here is the error message/code `Error: unexpected '=' in:
"HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df |>
  mutate(B36 = recode(B36, 1 ="`

Comment: Here is the code as it stands now   `HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df |>
  mutate(B36 = recode(B36, 1 = "Cosecha Anterior/Previous Harvest",  2 = "Otro Agricultor/Other Farmer",  3 = "Comprada como Grano/Purchased as Grain",  4 = "Semilla Envasada Comprada/Purchased Packaged Seed", 5 = "Recibido de ONG", 6 = "DICTA/SAG", 7 = "CIAL", 99 = "Otra/Other"))|>
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(B36))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x="Fuente de Semilla/Seed Source", 
       y="Productores Individuales/Individual Producers") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))`

Comment: `Error: unexpected '=' in:
"HND_plotlevel_Sec_B_df |>
  mutate(B36 = recode(B36, 1 ="`

Comment: Please add sample data. Just copy your original data (or a subset of it if it's huge) and paste as a code.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `as.factor()` on something, R guesses the order of the "levels" of the factor, defaulting to alphabetical. In this case, you want to specify a custom order for the levels. In fact, with `factor()` we can wrap the ordering and the recoding step together:

```
data.frame(B36 =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L)) |>   ## sample data
  mutate(
    B36 = factor(
      B36,
      levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 99),
      labels = c(
        "Cosecha Anterior/Previous Harvest",
        "Otro Agricultor/Other Farmer",
        "Comprada como Grano/Purchased as Grain",
        "Semilla Envasada Comprada/Purchased Packaged Seed", 
        "Recibido de ONG",
        "DICTA/SAG",
        "CIAL",
        "Otra/Other"
      )
    )
  )
```

You can save this result as an update to your data frame, and then continue with plotting or anything else.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks so much for your time with this. I ran the code as you supplied it, and this is how it returned: ```{r}  B36
1      Otra/Other
2      Otra/Other
3      Otra/Other
4      Otra/Other
5 Recibido de ONG
6 Recibido de ONG```

Comment: Incidentally, is that what you would have expected?  It returned the first six values variable B36.  I got a bunch of questions and we haven't got to the chart yet lol.  First of all, how did R know where to grab the data?  Your code does seem to indicate that overtly, and I've been dealing with a few different dataframes in the editor and console.  So how does R know from whence to grab the data set to refactor?!?

Comment: Secondly, with this bit of code here, what are you telling R when you write: ```{r} data.frame(B36 =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L))```  I understand that the `L` means discrete integer, but what does the `99` and the `5` mean?

Comment: Lastly, so I tried to hook up the code that you had written out and connect it to the ggplot part.  In between your last and second to last closed parentheses, I added the code ` ) geom_bar()+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))  ) `  But this didn't work.  It said:

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `B36 = +...`.
Caused by error in `factor(B36, levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 99), labels = c("Cosecha Anterior/Previous Harvest",
    "Otro Agricultor/Other Farmer", "Comprada como Grano/Purchased as Grain",
    "Semilla Envasada Comprada/Purchased Packaged Seed", "Recibido de ONG", "DICTA/SAG", "CIAL", "Otra/Other")) +
    geom_bar()`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Did I insert the ggplot code in the wrong place maybe?

Comment: Maybe it's be easier to switch over to mtcars as an example - that wouldn't be so clunky with the variable names etc?

Comment: `mtcars %>% 
data.frame(cyl =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L)) |>
  mutate(
    cyl = factor(
      cyl,
      levels = c(4,6,8),
      labels = c(
        "Four Cylinder",
        "Six Cylinder",
        "Eight Cylinder"
      )
    )
  )`

Comment: Is there a better way for me to transcribe that code onto this platform?  Its such a mess when I copy and paste it, and I can't get it to look nice and orderly.  How do I get so that it allows me to align the code chucks in conventional ways, like you did in your answer above?

Comment: There's not much you can do for formatting in comments. You're better off editing your question. But your problem is that you aren't ever calling `ggplot()`, you're going straight to `geom_bar()`. You can't just add `+ geom_bar()` to a data frame and get a plot, you need to start with `ggplot(name_of_your_data, aes(x = your_x_column)) + geom_bar()`. You should run `your_data = your_data |> mutate(...)` to modify your data, setting the factor levels in the desired order, then on the next line run `ggplot(your_data, ...`

Comment: Ok thank you for that insight.  So I completely reformated the original question at the top of the post (is that ok to change it so drastically?) I wanted to use the mtcars dataset and plug in the code that you had crafted.  Does that represent what you were thinking?

Comment: It's usually poor form to edit a question heavily after it has been answered.

Comment: I think the pipe is confusing you. When you write `mtcars %>% data.frame(cyl =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L))` that is the same as `data.frame(mtcars, cyl =  c(99L, 99L, 99L, 99L, 5L, 5L))`, which is an error. `mtcars` is already a data frame, so it doesn't make sense to put it inside `data.frame`.

Comment: You could try `my_data = mtcars |> mutate(
    cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4,6,8), labels = c("Four Cylinder", "Six Cylinder", "Eight Cylinder")))` and then you can run `ggplot(my_data, aes(x = cyl)) + geom_bar()`. For a bar plot, your plot code needs both a data frame and a column mapped to `x` inside `aes()`.